# Mysql Large Table Join Query very slow not Key indexes issue

Tags: mysql, query-performance

```
SELECT  t1.*
    FROM  
      ( SELECT  key_a,key_b,MAX(date) as date
            FROM  large_table
            WHERE  date <= **20150126**
            group by  key_a,key_b 
      ) AS t2
    JOIN  large_table AS t1 USING(key_a,key_b ,date)
```

> large_table = 1,223,001,206 rows of data

```
Primary Key key_a,key_b,date
key on key_b
key on date
```

There are numerous empty dates between rows for a & b that I want the most recent behind or on the **"Date"** entered.

Is it the Mysql Join settings causing it to be slow ?

I can copy the entire set of **a & b** data with an INSERT to a temp table just by selecting all the rows and then run the same query on the temp table, but why do multi queries (insert selected, then select from) when only 1 is needed.

The query above only has 4,128,548 total results in the temp insert all dates table, and the date specific returns under 180,000 total.

Not table optimization, not keys, is it Max sort length, Join Buffer size , I have 128 gig ram, on a 32 core server running this, there is no reason for it to be slow, just never bulk insert this large of a single table to run Join queries on prior if anyone else has dealt with tables this size any info greatly appreciated.

Edited query, yes it's late long day had Distinct when it wasn't needed or in actual query

Comment: This is true, yes that might have been a typo addition to the post here was looking at a couple queries will remove, yes it's not suppose to be there

Comment: Keep the composite key, and drop the others. Rearrange the composite key from sparse to dense (or is it dense to sparse, I can never remember). Also (and this just a personal quirk), don't use USING. it's confUSING

Comment: Actually the other keys are used in other queries that don't use the start field of the primary.  Tried this in a number of ways, nothing works well using the Max(date), I think is the biggest issue causing it to scan the whole table. Think I might be pushing the limits beyond with a table over a billion rows, to actually add much into the sorting of the primary key.  Pulling out a key date or key second field is instantaneous nearly, as well pulling out a whole field 1 & 2 to do the insert of 4 million plus rows is 4 - 5 seconds.  Think I'm stuck with multi queries.

Comment: Thanks for the hints Strawberry :) Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
        WHERE  date <= **20150126**
        group by  key_a,key_b
```

needs an index *starting* with `date`.  It's about doing what you can with the `WHERE` clause, not sparse or dense.

Then...  Since the inner query references only 3 columns, building a 'covering' index may be useful.  (Probably useful in your case.)  So, tack on the other two fields, in either order.  Such as

```
INDEX(`date`, key_a, key_b)
```

For MyISAM this step is critical.  For InnoDB, this is redundant, since each secondary key (such as your `INDEX(date)`) implicitly includes the rest of the fields of the PK.

No, the `PRIMARY KEY(key_a, key_b, date)` cannot serve the purpose.  It's in the wrong order.  Also, it is (if you are using InnoDB) "clustered" with the index.

> The query above only has 4,128,548 total results in the temp insert all dates table, and the date specific returns under 180,000 total.

Sorry, I had trouble parsing that.  I assume you are saying 4M rows had 'date<...' and the subquery delivered only 180K rows.  Hence, the outer query also returned 180K rows.

The first goal is to get through the 4M rows as efficiently as possible.  With the index I propose, that might be about 20K blocks (@16KB each) of index scanning.  That's 300MB.

Next the `MAX` and `GROUP BY` are performed.  At 300MB, this will involve a disk tmp table.  (See `max_heap_size` and `max_tmp_table_size`.)

Then comes the `JOIN` to fetch `t1.*`.  You are using a good technique for fetching a bunch of rows from a huge table, where you need a `GROUP BY` (or `LIMIT` or ...) that is clumsy when done the obvious way.  It goes like this:  Write the subquery to find the PKs.  Get the best index for it.  Then `JOIN` on the PK.

Now for the `JOIN`.  (Again, I assume InnoDB.)  Since you are `JOINing` on the PK, each lookup into `t1` will be efficient -- drill down the PK's BTree to find a row.  Do that 180K times.

If those 180K lookups are scattered around the table, then this *could* be 180K disk hits.

Total effort:  20K + 180K = 200K disk hits, possibly less.  On commodity spinning disks, this would take about 30 *minutes* (plus time for the tmp table).  (No, only one core will be used.  Anyway, I/O is probably the bottleneck.)

`OPTIMIZE TABLE` -- almost always useless.

I assume innodb_buffer_pool_size is about 90G?  If things are going to be cached, that is where it would happen (for InnoDB).  Since 200K blocks is 3GB, it could be easily cached.  That is, if you run the query twice, the first might be 30 minutes, but the second might be less than 3 minutes.

To get more numbers, you could do:

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...;
SHOW SESSION STATUS;
```

and look for 'Handler%', '%sort%', 'Innodb%' and maybe a few others.

What version are you running?  Recent versions have a leapfrog technique that works better for max+groupby than what I described.  I think it is called MRR.  If so, your PK is actually optimal.  (Hmmm... I should play around with that.)

`PARTITIONing` -- I don't see any benefit (for this query).

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.